# Custom Identity Server 4 deployed on Azure App Service endpoints exposed via Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, identityserver4, azure-api-management

I have created an Identity Server 4 based application using .NET Core 3.0, and deployed it to an Azure App Service running on a Windows hosting environment.

I also created an Azure API Management service and am trying to expose Identity Server endpoints through API Management only.

Is this a good design or a bad design? Should I expose Identity Server 4 endpoints directly?

Behind API Management, I have a few other API that should only be accessed by valid end users.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a good design or a bad design? Should I expose Identity Server
>   4 endpoints directly?

In fact,there is no standard answer for such question,however i tried to provide some references and suggestions here.

In my opinion, it depends on what features you involves. As i know,Identity Server 4 is an OpenID Connect and OAuth 2.0 framework for ASP.NET Core.In other words to say, it's generally a middleware for authentication.

Authenticate feature could be supported by APIM as well. Additional,APIM supports more features.Such as [Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-key-concepts#--groups) ans [Subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-subscriptions) to control the roles and users in your API accesses.Or you could define many strategies in the [Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/policy-samples) definition.The monitor logs could be easily captured into azure storage or azure event hub for analysis.

Anyway,for supporting more features, i would suggest you using APIM directly.